# Javascript calculation resulting NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form to calculate the total value from a form but it results in a nan error even though the values of the html inputs is numerical. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementsByName("optradio").value;
  var z = document.getElementsByName("extra-hours").value;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="25">Half day (3hrs)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="50">Full day (6hrs)
</label>
<input type="number" value="" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" name="extra-hours">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: @canon why so ????

Comment: [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) is useful for debugging. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cycle through the radios to get the value. getElement**s**ByName returns multiple elements.

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="25">Half day (3hrs)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="50">Full day (6hrs)</label>

<input type="number" value="" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" name="extra-hours">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
  function valueOfRadio(name) {

    // Get all of the radios by name
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(name); 

     // Go through each one
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      // If it's checked, lets return it's value
      if (radios[i].checked) {
        return radios[i].value;
      }
    }  
    
  }
  
  function myFunction() {
    // Go get the right radio value
    var y = valueOfRadio('optradio');
    // Same problem here. Multiple returned, but we know we only have one element so we index to 0. 
    //You could alternatively use getElementsById for this which will return a single node.
    var z = document.getElementsByName("extra-hours")[0].value;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName returns an array and you have to test all the radios to see if they are checked.

Try it:

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="25">Half day (3hrs)
    </label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="50">Full day (6hrs)</label>

    <input type="number" value="" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" id="extra-hours">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("optradio");

    var y = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {

            y += +radios[i].value;


        }
    }
        var z = document.getElementById("extra-hours").value;
        var x =  +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just wanted to write it. Upwote

Comment: No, it does not return an _array_; it returns an array-_like_ object. That's an important distinction.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't know. Can you tell me any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Actually getElementsByName returns array of elements with the name given, name optradio is allocated for 2 radio buttons, so you need to do like this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var radioarray = document.getElementsByName("optradio");
  var y;
  for (var i = 0; i < radioarray.length; i++) {
    if (radioarray[i].checked) {
      y = radioarray[i].value;
    }
  }

  var z = document.getElementsByName("extra-hours")[0].value;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="25">Half day (3hrs)
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="50">Full day (6hrs)
</label>
<input type="number" value="" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" name="extra-hours">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using a select instead of radio buttons, and it looks a little more compact and clean. I also used jQUery instead of plain Javascript because the code is a lot cleaner.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var result =  parseInt($("[name=optradio]").val()) + parseInt($("[name=extra-hours]").val());
  $("#result").text(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="optradio">
  <option value="25">Half day (3hrs)
  <option value="50">Full day (6hrs)
</select>
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" name="extra-hours">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByName("...")
```

returns a node list, not an individual node. You should use an id to select just a single node (preferred). That is

```
var y = document.getElementById("optradio").value
var z = document.getElementById("extra-hours").value
```

The properties "name" and "id" have different meanings, so make sure you use the one you actually mean.

If you want a unique identifier, use "id", if you want to group a selection of your DOM elements, use "name".

Additionally, the value for the radio button is always the same, you need to apply it conditionally based on the 'selected' property.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var half = document.getElementById("half");
  var full = document.getElementById("full");
  var y = half.checked ? half.value : full.value;
  var z = document.getElementById("extra-hours").value;
  var x = +y + +z;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="half" value="25" checked>Half day (3hrs)
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="full" value="50">Full day (6hrs)
</label>
<input type="number" value="" min="0" max="6" class="form-control" id="extra-hours">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Finally, although I'm not going to show it, you're probably best learning jQuery now; everything else uses jQuery. Everyone uses jQuery because it's better than base javascript. As Christian Juth showed in his answer, you probably want to make it a selection box, too.